# How to repaint JSF page when method bean is executed?

Tags: java, jsf-1.2

I want to delete al jsf components in a jsf and repaint it when i change value in a combo box and don't know how to do it. I need it because i have some java ifs whose paint diferent components in the page.

This is the code:

```
<%
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    PreguntasBean preguntasBean = (PreguntasBean) facesContext
            .getApplication()
            .createValueBinding("#{PreguntasBean}")
            .getValue(facesContext);
    preguntasBean.buscaTipoPregunta();

%>
        <h:outputText value="Selecciona un tipo de pregunta" />
        <h:selectOneMenu 
            id="tipoSeleccionado" value="#{PreguntasBean.tipos}" valueChangeListener="#{PreguntasBean.muestraPregunta}" onchange="submit()">
            <f:selectItems value="#{PreguntasBean.tiposValue}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>


        <h:outputText value="Enunciado " />
        <h:inputText value="#{PreguntasBean.preguntaParaGuardar.enunciado}" />

        <%if(preguntasBean.getValor().equals("1") || preguntasBean.getValor().equals("2") || preguntasBean.getValor().equals("3")){ %>

            <%if(preguntasBean.getValor().equals("2")){ %>
                    <h:outputText value="Opcion 1" />
                    <h:inputText value="" />
                    <h:outputText value="Opcion 2" />
                    <h:inputText value="" />
            <%} %>
            <h:outputText value="Sentencia" />
            <h:inputText value="#{PreguntasBean.sentencia}" />
            <%if(preguntasBean.getValor().equals("3")){ %>
                <h:outputText value="Texto fin" />
                <h:inputText value="" />
            <%} %>
            <h:commandButton value="Añadir sentencia" action="#{PreguntasBean.addSentencia}"/>
            <h:dataTable border="1" var="tablaSentencias" value="#{PreguntasBean.listaSentencias}" binding ="#{PreguntasBean.tabla}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Sentencias" />
                    </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{tablaSentencias.sentencia}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Acción" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:commandButton value="Borrar" action="#{PreguntasBean.borraSentencia}" />
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        <%} %>
```

So when i change the selectOneMenu I want to delete all outputtexts, inputs, datatables... (not the VO, only jsf tags).

Comment: Ouch, why JSF 1.2 and JSPs? Your life becomes so much easier if you can use JSF 2.x and Facelets, for example combined with Primefaces. JSF 1.2 has no built-in Ajax support which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm developing an Alfresco app and only supports JSF 1.2 :( this is the main problem

Comment: In this day and age, I wouldn't know what to advise you other than rerendering the page through a javascript onChange event. 5 years ago I would recommend adding Richfaces 3.3 to your technology stack to add ajax support to JSF 1.2, but that is simply not good advice today since its outdated, unsupported and doesn't even work properly in modern IE versions.

Comment: Can't use Js, i do a submit in onchange event and i can't add Richfaces or use ajax because alfresco hate it xD

Comment: At this point I'd put Alfresco outside with the garbage and start researching decent up-to-date tools to use.

Comment: But it isnt a valid solution, must use alfresco i havn't choice

Comment: I'd find an Alfresco forum and post your questions there, its not realistic to ask for a solution from a JSF perspective when you are limited by exterior junk. I have -no- clue how to help you when you can basically do nothing at all without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only need to delete <% %> conditionals and use this

```
rendered="#{PreguntasBean.valor =='3'}"
```